# Semicircumference, and tangent circumference satisfying certain conditions.

Tags: geometry

Please suppose you have a semicircumference of diameter AB, and radius r. Please help me to determine the radius of a tangent circumference in the point D of the diameter AB, and tangent in the point E to the semicircunference, satisfying the condition that, if C is the center of the tangent circumference, the following relation is true: AD + DC + CE = r

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a picture of the situation made in Paint (I added the point $O$ as the center of the semicircle).

[image: Semicircle]

Let $s$ be the radius of the small circle. We want to express $s$ in terms of $r$ under the restriction that $2s + AD = r$.

The triangle $\triangle OCD$ is right, with a right angle in $D$. The lengths of the sides in that triangle are $CD = s$, $OD = r - AD$ and $OC = r-s$. The Pythagorean theorem then gives
$$
(r-s)^2 = (r-AD)^2 + s^2
$$
But since $AD = r - 2s$, this gives
$$
(r-s)^2 = (r - (r - 2s))^2 + s^2\\
(r-s)^2 = 5s^2\\
-4s^2 - 2rs +r^2 = 0\\
s = \frac{2r \pm \sqrt{4r^2 + 16r^2}}{-8}\\
s = \frac{2r \pm 2r\sqrt{5}}{-8}\\
s = \frac{r}{4}(\sqrt{5} - 1)\approx 0.31r
$$
where I chose the positive solution, since $s$ has positive length.

Comment: Thank you very much for having considered my request.